# Not able to print the lattitude and longitude position

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am making an app that gives the weather details of the place.I am not able to print the latitude and longitude position.I have called the required objects in the getLocation method.I feel my code is all right but i am not able to print the latitude and longitude position .

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/screens/loading_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: LoadingScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

LoadingScreen.dart

```
import 'package:clima/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

const APIkey = '92e463e6**********************';
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}
double MyMarginAsDouble;
double latitude,longitude;
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
void initState(){//if i call getlocation inside init maethod it automatically gets the location without the need of a button
  super.initState();
  getLocation();
}
  Future<void> getLocation()
  async {
    location ob= new location();
   await ob.getCurrentLocation();
  }
Future<void> getData()
async {
  var url = Uri.parse('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=$APIkey');
  //var url = Uri.parse('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=92e463e6**********************');
  var response = await http.get(url);
 //code which tells different thing 200 - success 404-failure
  if(response.statusCode==200)
    {
      String data = response.body;
      print(data);
      var longitude = jsonDecode(data)['coord']['lon'];
      print(longitude);
      var weatherData = jsonDecode(response.body)['weather'][0]['description'];
      var weatherid = jsonDecode(response.body)['weather'][0]['id'];
      print(weatherData);
      print(weatherid);
      var temp = jsonDecode(response.body)['main']['temp'];
      print(temp);
      var name = jsonDecode(response.body)['name'];
      print(name);
    }
  else
    {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Location.dart

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class location{
  double latitude;
  double longitude;
  Future<void> getCurrentLocation()
  async {
    try{
      LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low); //high is battery consuming
      LocationPermission permission1 = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
      latitude=position.latitude;
      longitude=position.longitude;
      print(longitude);
      print(latitude);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      print(e);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I have edited your question to keep privacy. Please, never share private keys on public visible sites. That can lead you into huge expenses and lose a lot of money.

Comment: Thank You .I am a student so it dosent matter much :)

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to print"?  Do you get an error of some sort or just no output?  (If no output, do you get the print(e) message from your try/catch block?)

Comment: Just no output.